# Using CASE in SELECT to filter out NULL records

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I need to filter through different joins to pick the first 4 in a list of 10 however due to inconsistencies they don't all start at 1 and some have gaps.

I have the following code to populate the first of the 4 in the list

```
COALESCE (CASE 
WHEN 1 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END,
WHEN 2 IS NOT NULL THEN 2 END,
WHEN 3 IS NOT NULL THEN 3 END,
WHEN 4 IS NOT NULL THEN 4 END,
WHEN 5 IS NOT NULL THEN 5 END,
WHEN 6 IS NOT NULL THEN 6 END
 ) AS COL1
```

this works fine, the issue is when I go to do the second column. It returns the same value as I'm not able to compare to the previous COL1  as it is an alias.

Any help would be great!

Comment: just use conditions that limits the amount searched to the first 4 of each join this way it wont matter if they start with 1 or not.

Comment: Sample data with query, with expected results.  you may be able to use a window function like `row_number over (partition by.... order by....) as RN` to generate a row number and then filter `where RN <=4...`

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server, this is almost impossible to do with `case` statements -- they will get very complicated.

Instead, you can unpivot the data into rows and then re-aggregate the data into separate columns, filtering out the `NULL`s along the way.  Here is an example using `outer apply`:

```
select . . ., x.*
from . . . outer apply -- all your joins go here
     (select max(case when seqnum = 1 then col end) as col_1,
             max(case when seqnum = 2 then col end) as col_2,
             max(case when seqnum = 3 then col end) as col_3,
             max(case when seqnum = 4 then col end) as col_4             
      from (select col, row_number() over (order by ordering) as seqnum
            from (values (t1.col, 1), (t2.col, 2), . . . 
                 ) v(col, ordering)
            where col is not null
           ) v
     ) x
```